# Do while loop not working, only one result is diplayed

Tags: php, sql, loops, while-loop, do-while

Having a bit of trouble with a do wile loop not looping..
There are currently 2 results in the SQL that should be returned but it only shows one.

**SQL. - the two results it should find**

```
array('bid'=>4,'bname'=>'fdsfsdaf','section'=>'Network','btype'=>'Activity','breq'=>'fdsfsd','bnotes'=>'fdsfdsf','image'=>'Badges/Network/2inchsquare.png'),
  array('bid'=>3,'bname'=>'Test','section'=>'Network','btype'=>'Activity','breq'=>'dfsfds','bnotes'=>'fsdfs','image'=>'Badges/Network/2inchsquare.png')
);
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php
require_once('inc/global.php');
include('inc/auth.php');
mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM badges WHERE section = 'Network'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$bnetwork = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin</title>
<link href="css/admin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="listtable">

<table class="contacts">
        <tr>
            <td class="contactDept" width="20%">Badge Name</td>
            <td class="contactDept" width="20%">Section</td>
            <td class="contactDept" width="20%">Badge Type</td>
            <td class="contactDept" width="20%">Pic</td>
            <td class="contactDept" width="10%">Edit</td>
            <td class="contactDept" width="10%">Del</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<?php do { ?>       
        <ul>
            <li class="badgeName"><?php echo $bnetwork['bname']; ?></li>
            <li class="badgeSection"><?php echo $bnetwork['section']; ?></li>
            <li class="badgeType"><?php echo $bnetwork['btype']; ?></li>
            <li class="badgePic"><img src="<?php echo $bnetwork['image'];?>" width="30px" height="30px"></li>
            <li class="badgeEdit"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li class="badgeDel"><a href="#">Del</a></li>
        </ul>

<?php } while($bnetwork = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know the table shouldnt be in **LI** tags, i was just trying just in case it didn't like **TD** tags for some unknown reason.
Please tell me if you can work out why it only shows one result.

Comment: Why are you using `do { } while ();` instead of `while () { }`?  Do you know *for a fact* that you will always have at least one result row?

Comment: Im newish to php, what should i put and where?

Comment: Could you do something simpler like echo "test" or increment a variable in the loop and see how many iterations actually occur?

Answer (score 0):

The while loop should be adequete. Also you don't need echo and the ';' when just displaying a variable in your HTML. You can just use an '=' to mean echo when it immediately follows an opening php tag.
I hope this helps.

```
<? while($n = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <ul>
            <li class="badgeName"><?=$n['bname']?></li>
            <li class="badgeSection"><?=$n['section']?></li>
            <li class="badgeType"><?=$n['btype']?></li>
            <li class="badgePic"><img src="<?=$n['image']?>" width="30px" height="30px"></li>
            <li class="badgeEdit"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li class="badgeDel"><a href="#">Del</a></li>
        </ul>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunatly its not working. Its not showing any results at all. I put a print_r at the top and its showing one result in the array.

Comment: I just fixed the mysql_fetch_assoc it was misspelled. Recopy and paste :)

Comment: Does it matter that i didnt use $n

Comment: I used: <? while($bnetwork = mysql_fetch_accoc($result)) { ?> and left the echo's as they were originally.

Comment: Yes, your assigning each returned row to the $n variable while looping through all your returned rows. It creates a temporary array in the $n variable that is key(column name) => value(column value). So you can extract the column values by name by getting the value of $n['column_name'].

Comment: That is not spelled correctly it is mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: If you're using $bnetwork then all the <?=$n['column']?> need to be changed to <?=$bnetwork['column']?>, if you're asking if it HAS to be $n then no it's a variable name of your choice not a set thing.

Comment: You're retrieving the associative array twice, try removing the $bnetwork = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 on line 7. It's not being used for anything.